# closing the initial form in multi-form application

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, user-interface

In my application there is a login form, after logging in successfully I show the other form after I close the second form the application keeps running so I have to stop it from visual studio.

```
public partial class login : Form
{

    DB.DB con = DB.DB.singelDB();
    GUI.Welcome wlcm = new GUI.Welcome();
    private String usertype;
    public login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void setUserType()
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked) { usertype = "employee"; }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked) { usertype = "patient"; }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Please select your type!"); }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.uid = textBox1.Text;  
        con.password = textBox2.Text;
        con.Initialize();
        
        setUserType();
        try {
            if (con.OpenConnection()) {
                this.Hide();
                wlcm.Show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

when the enter button is clicked I hide the first form and show the second one. When I close the second form the application keeps running

Comment: FYI: code wrapper is 3 backticks not 3 single quotes

Comment: You can retrieve the login form from the Application.OpenForms and then close it when you close your second form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the `FormClosing` event and check if user has clicked on the close button, and if that is the case you can exit the application.

```
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
```